# ingress-controller and Google kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created an ingress resource in my Kubernetes cluster on google cloud.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gordion
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: gordion-ingress
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: gordion-certificate,gordion-certificate-backend
spec:
  rules:
  - host: backend.gordion.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 80
```

Everything works. However, I have not created any `ingress-controller`. [the official docs state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) that it must have it.

> You must have an ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress. Only
>   creating an Ingress resource has no effect.

So where is my ingress-controller if my routing actually works? how do I see its configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), when you create an Ingress object, the built-in GKE ingress controller will take care of creating the appropriate HTTP(S) load balancer which conforms to your Ingress and its Service(s). For more information, have a look at this [Google Cloud Document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) on "HTTP(S) load balancing with Ingress".

Comment: does it make the nginx-controller redundant actually?

Comment: @LiranC if you install the Nginx controller on GKE then that would replace the GKE Ingress controller. There wouldn't be any redundancy.  A reason to choose Nginx over the default GKE controller is for additional features which are explained in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke).

Answer (score 2):

In GKE, if you do not specify the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation, the GCE L7 load balancer controller (GLBC) will be used by default (it is actually equivalent to setting `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce`). This controller will be automatically provisioned and will rely on GCP's global HTTP(s) load balancer.

You can find more information on this topic on the [GLBC GitHub's page](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) as well as [in this How-To article](https://kubectl.wordpress.com/2019/09/14/using-gclb-as-an-ingress-controller/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes your ingress will work like this if you give it a NodePort service and a service behind... But you could have only created a LoadBalancer service and have the same result.

If you don't have any ingress-controller some of your configuration is not good as you are referencing some nginx ingress controller configuration (the rewrite).

The aim of an ingress controller is to load balance http-traffic for multiple apps inside your cluster, meaning, you only create one provider (here GCP) LB for multiple  domains/path. This allows you to make some finops, not having multiple public IP and LB resources created for each of your apps.

In the documentation you posted in the pre-requisites that you mentionned there is a list of available solution like nginx-ingress controller, traefik....

How to use them:

- First create an ingress like you did, remove the nginx rewrite and put * to hosts (that's a default conf for example)
- Once the controller is up, for each app needing to have a path to the internet create an ingress with your ingress-specific annotations.